# Pong reflector math?

Tags: pong

I am making a Pong clone and I am treating my variables in this way:

```
direction = a value from 0 to 2*pi 
distX = cos(direction)*speed of the ball
distY = sin(direction)*speed of the ball

on update:
ball's x position += distX
ball's y position += distY
```

I can already handle the flipping of directions correctly when a ball hits a wall (just reflect at 90 degrees) but what about a paddle? I don't know how to best handle the angle and speed of the ball after it connects.

Does it depend on where it hits on the paddle? Does it matter if the paddle is moving? etc

I don't know a reasonable way to handle the math here.

Comment: This belongs on the gamedev exchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no "right" way of doing this. You're the one who's writing the code, and unless you've got some strict specifications, you can handle it how you prefer much.

Basically, you can handle the ball-paddle collision the same way you handle a ball-wall collision, i.e. by simply calculating the reflection angle, and assigning it to `direction`.

If you want to increase the reflection angle proportionally with the paddle speed, you can simply apply some kind of weight to the new `direction`.

But it's really up to you.

Anyway, if you provide, for example, the code where you handle the paddle speed, someone could give you further indication.

Comment: Right now I am holding my paddle speed constant. Movement in either direction will move the paddle the same rate.

Comment: Well, in that case I really don't see any need to increase or decrease ball speed. You could however speed the ball up in case the paddle is hit near the corner. It should not be difficult to retrieve the collision point and increase `ball speed` based upon that.

Comment: My concern outside of that is angling. Should angles changed based on where it hits the paddle? If so, what is a reasonable way to change it?

Comment: The first thing I feel to recommend is to try and play a Pong clone. Look closely at how the ball behave when it hits the paddle. Other than that, I think that commonly the angle becomes wider when the ball is hit by a fast-moving paddle, rather than a fixed one. So I think this could be a good starting point. Then, you can tweak it how you prefer.

Comment: My concern is that since I am controlling the paddle with the keyboard, the speed of the paddle is constant. Therefore any time the paddle is moving and the ball hits it, it would be changing the ball in the same fashion every time?

Comment: Not if you make the speed change depend on the collision location, i.e. if the ball hits the paddle near one of its edges, the speed increment (or decrement) is bigger.

Comment: That is the approach I think I want to take, but I don't know how to best mathematically change the direction/speed since I am currently handling things the way I outlined in my OP. Perhaps I need different speed variables for X and Y?

Answer (score 0):

I presume your paddles are rectangles then? For simplicity, lets assume that the ball may only strike the face of the paddle (that is, not the corners or the sides).

Q: Does it depend on where it hits on the paddle?
A: If the paddle is an axis-aligned rectangle and the ball may only hit its surface, then no.

Q: Does it matter if the paddle is moving?
A: This is your choice. Game physics are not real physics, so you are free to do whatever makes the game play the best.

The first thing is that rotating the ball's direction by 90 degrees does not accurately deflect the ball off the wall. Consider the extreme case where the ball hits the wall dead on. If I rotated the ball by 90 degrees, the ball would then travel parallel next to the wall.

I believe what you are currently doing, and just stated a little confusingly, that if the ball hits a vertical wall, you reverse the horizontal direction of the ball. This is, of course, not equivalent to rotating the ball's direction by 90 degrees.

If I wanted to impart speed from the paddle to the ball, I would treat the ball's movement as a vector and the paddle's movement as a vector. I'd then add these two vectors together. To control how much velocity is imparted to the ball, I'd use a coefficient (lets call it `k`), and if the ball needs to maintain a constant speed, I'd normalize the ball's final velocity vector (but since you are storing speed instead of x,y components, that isn't necessary).

```
if (ball hits paddle):
  k = 0.5;
  // paddle only moves horizontally, which simplifies the math
  paddle_vx = paddle_speed * paddle_xdirection;
  ball_vx = cos(ball_direction) * speed + k*paddle_vx; 
  ball_vy = - sin(ball_direction) * speed // flips from the collision
  ball_direction = atan2(ball_vy, ball_vx);
  ball_speed = 100; // always constant
```

Comment: I should clarify (as I likely misspoke): When I collide with a wall, all I do is flip the direction to its negative. Even if I initialize the ball as heading straight up against the wall, it'll just bounce back and forth between the walls forever.